# Is it possible to set default query parameters on an resource in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

If I have a simple resource defined like the following, it's my understanding that I can call the `Receipt.query()` method to get a collection back from the server.  It's also my understanding that if I call `Receipt.query({freightBill: 123})`, then freightBill gets added as a query parameter like `/distribution/inbound?freightBill=123`.  How could I pass query parameters in this fashion, but then from my factory, also add default query parameters for page, size and sort?

The resulting request might look like `/distribution/inbound?freightBill=123&page=0&size=20&sort=number,desc`

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .factory('receipts', function ($http, $resource, $location) {
    var search = $location.search();
    var page = search.page||0;
    var size = search.size||20;
    var sort = search.sort||'number,desc';

    return $resource('/distribution/inbound');
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

second parameter of the $resource is for default parameters. DOCS : [Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .factory('receipts', function ($http, $resource, $location) {
    return $resource('/distribution/inbound',{page:0,size:20,sort:'number,desc'});
  });
```

these make them 'defaults'. Meaning you can override by passing new values to `.query` like 
`Receipt.query({freightBill: 123,size:20,page:2})`

Comment: Can we set this default parameter to a specific method? For example, I want to send default parameter only in `PUT` method. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, check out the $resource documentation. You can define named "actions". Check out the credit card example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it was actually quite simple...  Simply appending the query parameters to the resource path worked.  When calling `Receipt.query({freightBill: 123})`, Angular intelligently appends `&freightBill=123` to the end of the path.  Without the page, size and sort parameters there, Angular just appends `?freightBill=123` since it's the only parameter.

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .factory('receipts', function ($http, $resource, $location) {
    var search = $location.search();
    var page = search.page||0;
    var size = search.size||20;
    var sort = search.sort||'number,desc';

    return $resource('/distribution/inbound?page=' + page + '&size=' + size + '&sort=' + sort);
  });
```